# Prevent jQuery.fn.extend from firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I put the following example

```
<script>

    $( "#buttom1" ).click(function() {
    console.log('ok')
    $.fn.thefuncion();


    });


    $.fn.thefuncion=function(){

    jQuery('#buttom2').click(function(){
     alert('ready')
     });
    }

</script>

    <input type="submit" name="button" id="buttom1" value="buttom 1">
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="buttom2" value="buttom 2">
```

the problem is that the alert appears the number of times the 1 button is pressed

I need regardless of the number of times the 1 button is pressed, only an alert is displayed  after pressing button 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it in a proper way. Do not bind events multiple times. That is unnecessary. you can achieve what you wanted in the form of event delegation.

```
$( "#buttom1" ).click(function() {
    jQuery('#buttom2').addClass("active");
});

jQuery(document).on('click','.active', function(){
    alert('ready')
});
```

where `document` will be the end point of event bubbling, From that the culprit who triggered the event will be caught and its event will be triggered if any. So traversing up to the document will be unnecessary. Instead of `document` pass any static closest parent of button `buttom2`

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/wwgpngdc/3/)

Comment: i need use the jQuery.fn.extend

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `.one()` function:

```
$( "#buttom1" ).one('click', function() {

    console.log('ok')
    $.fn.thefuncion();

});
```

This event will fire the first time button1 is clicked and the button2 event will only be set up once.